# Word 2008 macro to SVN ADD current document

Tags: macos, vba, svn, ms-word, applescript

I want to invoke "svn add" on the current Word 2008 document. I've got a shell script that will svn commit it later. I don't want that shell script to indiscriminately svn add files so I'd like to be able to do it from a button in Word 2008 tied to a macro or appleScript.

Answer (score 1):

Since Word 2008 doesn't have VBA, you'll need to use AppleScript.

Is there anything stopping you from using "do shell script" to do what you need?

You'll need the document path for svn add - see full name property in the [document class](http://www.microsoft.com/mac/developers/default.mspx?clr=99-25-0&ep=9&target=9635a2e8-234a-48f2-9586-f848ac8e3da21033&CTT=InContent)

Comment: the user is no longer active on the site. unfortunately I don't believe you'll ever receive a response on your answer.